# SQL query, what's `SELECT * FROM !.tables WHERE id = !`

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I never seen SQL like that before:

```
SELECT *
  FROM !.tables
 WHERE id = !
```

What's it doing?

Comment: you should add more details, does that query run under any php framework/pakcage/etc.

Comment: It's not pure MySQL; they do not list an exclamation mark as an operator on its own. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/non-typed-operators.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a parametrized query, however I've never seen exclamation points being used as placeholders. What library is the query being run through?

Comment: PHP using mysql_query if the (old) tags are anything to go by.

Comment: I have a feeling the mysql-query tag doesn't mean that.